# avconv with subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

It's seems like I never really manage to wrap my head around subprocess. This commandline works in bash

```
avconv -i "concat:/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment0.ts|/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment1.ts" -vcodec copy -acodec copy /tmp/test1.ts
```

Bu if I try this:

```
cmdline = ['avconv', '-i "concat:/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment0.ts|/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment1.ts"', '-vcodec copy', '-acodec copy', '/tmp/test1.ts']
subprocess.call(cmdline)
```

It exit avconv with the following error:

```
avconv version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:52:09 with gcc 4.6.3
Unrecognized option 'i "concat:/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment0.ts|/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment1.ts"'
Failed to set value '-vcodec copy' for option 'i "concat:/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment0.ts|/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment1.ts"'
1
```

I've tried some variants (including shell=True) but I can't figure out the problem.

### Update

Cjb made an answer that really worked. But my real code is more complicated. I believe it's hard to get something out of it. But I throw it in here just in case there is an obvoius problem that I missed.

```
def run_avconv(output_dir, fnames):
    full_fnames = [os.path.join(output_dir, fname.replace('\n', ''))
                   for fname in fnames]
    concatted_files = '|'.join(full_fnames)
    cmd_line = [AVCONV_CMD,
                '-i',
                '"concat:' + concatted_files + '"',
                '-vcodec',
                'copy',
                '-acodec',
                'copy',
                os.path.join(output_dir, 'out.ts')]
    subprocess.Popen(cmd_line)
```

the full_fnames variable is:

```
['/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment0.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment1.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment2.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment3.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment4.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment5.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment6.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment7.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment8.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment9.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment10.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment11.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment12.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment13.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment14.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment15.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment16.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment17.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment18.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment19.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment20.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment21.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment22.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment23.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment24.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment25.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment26.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment27.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment28.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment29.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment30.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment31.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment32.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment33.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment34.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment35.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment36.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment37.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment38.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment39.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment40.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment41.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment42.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment43.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment44.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment45.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment46.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment47.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment48.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment49.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment50.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment51.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment52.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment53.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment54.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment55.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment56.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment57.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment58.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment59.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment60.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment61.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment62.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment63.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment64.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment65.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment66.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment67.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment68.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment69.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment70.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment71.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment72.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment73.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment74.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment75.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment76.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment77.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment78.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment79.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment80.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment81.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment82.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment83.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment84.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment85.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment86.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment87.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment88.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment89.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment90.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment91.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment92.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment93.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment94.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment95.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment96.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment97.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment98.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment99.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment100.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment101.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment102.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment103.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment104.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment105.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment106.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment107.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment108.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment109.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment110.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment111.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment112.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment113.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment114.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment115.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment116.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment117.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment118.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment119.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment120.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment121.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment122.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment123.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment124.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment125.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment126.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment127.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment128.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment129.ts',
 '/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment130.ts']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with this:

```
cmdline = [
    'avconv',
    '-i',
    'concat:/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment0.ts|/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment1.ts',
    '-vcodec',
    'copy',
    '-acodec',
    'copy',
    '/tmp/test1.ts',
]
subprocess.call(cmdline)
```

You really want to pass each separate part as a different item in the list.

Comment: Thanks. It do work. But that was a simplified sample. So in my real code it still doesn't work. I will paste the real code as an edit. Maybe someone will see something wrong. Cause I don't... :-/

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @djc is correct, however if you wanted to work by copying and pasting a string, you can do something like this:

```
import shlex
from pprint import pprint

cmd = """avconv -i "concat:/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment0.ts|/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment1.ts" -vcodec copy -acodec copy /tmp/test1.ts"""
for_subprocess = shlex.split(cmd)
pprint(for_subprocess)

['avconv',
 '-i',
 'concat:/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment0.ts|/tmp/BABAR_AND_THE_A-011A-hts-a-v1-cc3651d01841d748_Layer6/6148_Period1/segment1.ts',
 '-vcodec',
 'copy',
 '-acodec',
 'copy',
 '/tmp/test1.ts']
```

Comment: Appears the syntax highlighter doesn't understand triple-quoted strings

Comment: +1 Thanks. Great alternative. Though I'm not sure it fixes my (new) problem now when I separated all parts. :-/